# If else statement malfunction in callback function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am learning Web development and using JavaScript and express to code the back-end. I can't figure out why my if else statement is malfunctioning. The problem is it only shows what is written in else statement on the website page. Below is my code -

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.get("/", function(request,response){

    var today = new Date();
    if(today.getDay() === 6 || today.getDay() === 7) {
        response.send("Yeh! it's the weekend");
    }else {
        response.send("Boo!, I have to work");
    }
});

app.listen(3000 , function() {
    console.log("Server is running at port 3000");
});
```

Comment: What exactly does "malfunctioning" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors/exceptions reported?

Comment: Also days are numbered from 0 through 6, so `getDay()` will never return 7.

Comment: I am using vscode. I am using node and running it on localhost port 3000. what happens with in my case is whenever i run the code in node, the website only give "Boo! I have to work" which is in else statement. It doesn't run the if statement. I have also tried the correct code (which is using 0 to 6 for days) but it still doesn't execute the if statement. today is sunday and it must show the content of if statement.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(today)` to see what the actual value is?

Answer (score 0):

```
sunday = 0
monday = 1
tuesday = 2
wednesday = 3
thursday = 4
friday = 5
saturday = 6
```

Comment: A little explanation wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I am using vscode. I am using node and running it on localhost port 3000. what happens with in my case is whenever i run the code in node, the website only give "Boo! I have to work" which is in else statement. It doesn't run the if statement. I have also tried the correct code (which is using 0 to 6 for days) but it still doesn't execute the if statement. today is sunday and it must show the content of if statement.

Comment: @karel what more is there to explain?

Comment: @AyushVerma did you forget to restart the server after changing the value?